# Last change date of file is resetting to current DateTime when looking at it in explorer

Tags: c#, windows, file, windows-explorer, file-attributes

I am currently writing a software in C# that downloads e-mails from an IMAP server.

The files are saved and the last write date is set to the email date.
At first everything seems to work, but when I'm surfing the folder where the files are saved with Windows explorer and select a file (not open it), sometimes it will change the last write time to the current DateTime.

Did someone experience this behavior before?

Comment: Are the files associated with outlook? Do you have the preview window on in explorer? Does the date gets resetted to the previous value if you select another file?

Comment: Try setting 1 file for testing to READ ONLY, then run the program, it should expose the culprit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.